# "upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream" error - Increasing buffers not working

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I've set up the Bitnami Nginx Open Source Stack at AWS. I've started creating an application using auth0 as my authentication service. After successful login, the code must be exchanged for an access token. This is done using `$auth0->exchange($url_with_params);`

However, this gives me the following error:

```
    2021/10/10 17:38:36 [error] 14305#14305: *9 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: [ip], server: api.redacted.com, request: "GET /login_callback?code=FKIk4X_uIgqKg-zo&state=40da33a1177fc8fbc275dcaf826fc819 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/opt/bitnami/PHP/var/run/www.sock:", host: "api.redacted.com", referrer: "https://deva.redacted.com/"
```

I've read a hundred posts saying that one must increase the `proxy_buffer_size` or the `fastcgi_buffer_size` to get rid of this error. I've tried increasing both parameters and restarted Nginx, but I keep getting the same error.

I've also tried to set `proxy_buffering off` and `fastcgi_buffering off`, but I still get the same error.

There must be something else going on here.
How can I log or see the actual response that Nginx refuses to handle?

Comment: Likely way too late for you, but for anyone else who lands here like I did, with a similar issue. I had to move my proxy buffer settings into my nginx site files (Inside my /etc/nginx/sites-available/site.com) instead of the nginx config itself. Not sure if that is an actual fix itself though, or just something weird with my digitalocean server setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
*_buffers 16 32k;
*_buffer_size 64k;
*_busy_buffers_size 64k;
```

Use the above values first and check whether it helps or not. If it doesn't work then you can gradually increase these values to 128k, 256k, and 512k respectively.